# Marcar lineas con caracteres no latinos en Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

quisiera saber si existe alguna forma para hacer una búsqueda en Notepad++ y marcar aquellas líneas que tengan algún carácter no latino. Las líneas tienen nombres e emails, pero en ciertos casos, tienen algún carácter cirílico, árabe, chino, japonés...

Por lo tanto, quisiera, o bien marcar aquellas que sólo tengan caracteres latinos + "@" + "." y tal vez números.

O bien todo aquel que no tenga caracteres que evidentemente no son parte de los emails.

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo que puedes utilizar es la opción de reemplazar con `regex` y buscar todos los caracteres que no sean [ASCII](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/)

Para hacerlo debes ir al menú buscar->reemplazar (Search->replace, si lo tienes instalado en inglés)

En la parte inferior izquierda seleccionar "Expresión regular" (Regular expression)

Y utilizar el siguiente `regex`

```
[^\x00-\x7F]+
```

Puedes reemplazar todos esos caracteres por un `string` vacío para eliminarlos y oprimir "Reemplazar todos" (Replace all)

**NOTA:** Depende de como esté escrito tu texto es posible que con ese `regex` también elimines los saltos de línea, o algunos tipos de comillas, por ejemplo estas: `“”`

Lo importante es que con el `regex` lo puedes hacer pero tal vez tengas que buscar un poco más para incluir únicamente los caracteres que deseas eliminar.

Si sólo deseas "marcar" la posición donde estén entonces puedes utilizar la pestaña "Marcar" (Mark) y presionar "Marcar todos" (Mark all).

PD. Yo lo tengo instalado en inglés y tal vez algún nombre de botón o función esté mal

Answer (score 0):

Si sólo deseas marcar letras, quizás sería más apropiado lo siguiente:

```
(?![a-zA-Z])\p{L}
```

Con Notepad++ tienes la opción de Marcar, disponible pulsando <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> (recuerda a marcar la casilla "expresión regular")

Explicado:

```
(?! # Lo que viene a continuación no debe ser...
    [a-zA-Z] ...una letra a-z o A-Z
)
\p{L} # Encontrar cualquier tipo de letra
```

Es decir, la idea es buscar cualquier tipo de letra y descartar las que son a-zA-Z